# how to print 8.00 instead of 8

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I need some help with this code. I do not know how to print the output as `8.00`. It always shows the number `8`. I tried `setprecision()` but I keep getting an error that `setprecision` is not a member of `std`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (void){
    float int1,int2,int3;
    char op;
    cout << "Enter operation: ";
    cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter number 1: ";
    cin >> int1;
    cout << "Enter number 2: ";
    cin >> int2;
    cout << "Enter number 3: ";
    cin >> int3;
    cout << "Answer: " << std::setprecision(2);
    
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            cout << int1 + int2 + int3;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << int1 - int2 - int3;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << int1 * int2 * int3;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << int1 / int2 / int3;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "what you inputted is not an operation...";
            break;
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

Comment: You should use `cout << "Answer: " << std::setprecision(2);` instead of `cout << "Answer: ";`, as @jerry-coffin recommends

Comment: "I tried precision but kept getting error code" means that your question would be better if you included that attempt you made and what actual error you got.

Comment: Why does your [mre] need to be longer than `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () { float int1 = 8; cout << int1 << '\n'; }`? (And why would you choose "int" as the name for a `float` variable?)

Comment: there is a constraint that I should use switch statement that identifies the answer of the inputted operator and 3 numbers, the data was int i replace it with float because the answer won't input the other decimal places

Comment: @EryPisalbon *"there is a constraint that I should use switch statement"* -- that constraint is not relevant here. We are not grading your homework. You are allowed to ask your question without the `switch`, then apply the answer to your code with the `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will generate proper output as needed. The output will show precision if and only if it is required.

For Example :

1. 2+2+ 2 = 6
2. 2.5 + 1 + 1 = 4.5
3. 2.3 + 5.8 + 1.6514 = 9.7514

Here is the code :

```
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    float int1,int2,int3;
    float answer;
    char op;
    cout << "Enter operation: ";
        cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter number 1: ";
        cin >> int1;
    cout << "Enter number 2: ";
        cin >> int2;
    cout << "Enter number 3: ";
        cin >> int3;
    cout << "Answer: ";
    
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            answer = int1 + int2 + int3;
            cout << answer;
            break;
        case '-':
            answer = int1 - int2 - int3;
            cout  << answer;
            break;
        case '*':
            answer = int1 * int2 * int3;
            cout  << answer;
            break;
        case '/':
            answer = int1 / int2 / int3;
            cout  << answer;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "wrong input";
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the int1,int2,int3 it was originally an int before i change the data type that's why I named it int1,int2,in3

Answer (score 0):

You should first `#include <iomanip>` to use `setprecision`. Also, you should add `cout << fixed`.

```cpp
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    float int1,int2,int3;
    char op;
    cout << "Enter operation: ";
        cin >> op;
    cout << "Enter number 1: ";
        cin >> int1;
    cout << "Enter number 2: ";
        cin >> int2;
    cout << "Enter number 3: ";
        cin >> int3;
    cout << "Answer: ";
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
            cout << int1 + int2 + int3;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << int1 - int2 - int3;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << int1 * int2 * int3;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << int1 / int2 / int3;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "wrong input";
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it still prints the whole number without .00

Comment: @EryPisalbon sorry, forgot to add `cout << fixed`, it should work now.